# PS pipe WorkingSet as variable

Tags: variables, powershell

I have this which gives me the WorkingSet memory usage I'm after:

```
$mem=Get-Process spiceworks | Select-Object Name,@{Name='WorkingSet';Expression={($_.WorkingSet/1KB)}}
```

But I'm looking to only have the actual amount as the variable so I can then work with that to monitor it. I want to set it so it alerts me if it goes over a specific amount so I can perform a clean stop of the relevant service and then E-mail me.
If someone can let me know how to just get the amount I would appreciate it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. So you want just the number as the result of this?

Comment: Yes - that is correct, just the number.

Comment: Well, then the answer given below by M. R. J.is just what you need ). -ExpandProperty parameter is a nice hack to get scalar values, although it's commonly used with properties of array type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to grab just a single property from the process:

```
$WorkingSet = Get-Process spiceworks |Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty WorkingSet
if($WorkingSet -gt 120MB) {
    # Send email
}
```